# Error while trying to connect to database through eclipse database development perspective

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

This is error stack trace i am getting...

Could not connect to mydb.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to mydb. (Error: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver)
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Error creating JDBC Connection connection to mydb. (Error: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver)
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

I am using oracle thin driver to connect to database..

SID: db

Host: localhost

Port number 1521

User name: system

Password:

Connection URL: jdbc:oraclethin:©lccalhost:1521:db

I can't even able to ping the database...

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your connection URL. It says `lccalhost` instead of `localhost`. Try:

```
jdbc:oraclethin:©localhost:1521:db
```

Furthermore, your log says `mydb` instead of `db` as stated in your connection settings. So, this may be another possible cause of fault.

Comment: @Rahulbujji If the answer helped you, you may mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using xpress edition 11-g and if so then try changing the SID from db to xe and then it should work fine .
If you are using the standard edition then you must check with the odbc jars .
Try adding odbc6 jar